# Angular 2 CSRF cookie not set in POST response header in Spring Security

Tags: spring, angular, cookies, spring-security, csrf

I have an Angular2 application that works with Spring. The backend (spring) runs on a other port so i configured the CORS as follow.

```
    public GlobalCorsfilter() {
super();
}

@Override
public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");

// without this header jquery.ajax calls returns 401 even after successful login and SSESSIONID being succesfully stored.
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Version");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type");

final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
if (request.getMethod() != "OPTIONS") {
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
} else {
    //
}
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}
}
```

This code works fine i guess because i don't get any errors.

The problem occurs when i try to POST something, but it works fine with a GET method. I have CSRF enabled in my spring configuration and i want it to keep it that way. I get a '403' code when i try to POST. This is my CookieFilter class for configuring CSRF.

```
public class CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,      HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws  ServletException, IOException {
// Spring put the CSRF token in session attribute "_csrf"
CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");

// Send the cookie only if the token has changed
String actualToken = request.getHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN");
if (actualToken == null || !actualToken.equals(csrfToken.getToken())) {
    // Session cookie that will be used by AngularJS
    CookieGenerator cookieGenerator = new CookieGenerator();
    cookieGenerator.setCookieName("CSRF-TOKEN");
    cookieGenerator.setCookieHttpOnly(false);
    cookieGenerator.setCookieMaxAge(-1);
    cookieGenerator.setCookiePath("/");
    cookieGenerator.addCookie(response, csrfToken.getToken());
}

filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

And here is my Spring Configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(new GlobalCorsfilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .........
```

I already added this line of code in Angular 2:

```
{provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('CSRF-TOKEN', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN')}
```

I get this message in the Response:

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Angular2 documentation if you use http method it takes care of CSRF by default, so you do not need to add any provider unless you want to have a custom XSRFstrategy.

> Angular's http has built-in support for the client-side half of this technique in its XSRFStrategy. The default CookieXSRFStrategy is turned on automatically. Before sending an HTTP request, the CookieXSRFStrategy looks for a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN and sets a header named X-XSRF-TOKEN with the value of that cookie.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#http

But as you can see in the link below you need to have a special configuration in spring in order to to allow JavaScript (i.e. AngularJS) to read it. In the documentation they named AngularJS but is the same for Angular 2+.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-cookie